# Excel data reader : variable list loses list content with Clear() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using an excel data reader based on this tutorial with online source code : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/reading-an-excel-file-using-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application-2693545577db

For my case, I'm trying to spice things up using let's say in the Models another class "Skills" and let's say each User has a public `List<Skills> Skillslist { get; set; }`

```cs
namespace ReadExcel.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public List<Skills> SkillsList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And let's say my class Skills is like this, and that each skills is unique to a UserModel :

```cs
namespace ReadExcel.Models
{
    public class Skills
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public int UserModelId { get; set; }
}
```

I have an Excel file made like this following :

```
     |     A     |         B      |
  1  |  Name     |     Skill      |
  2  |  John     | Accounting     |
  3  |  John     | Management     |
  4  |  John     | Production     |
  5  |  Liz      | Strategy       |
  6  |  Liz      | Fusion & Acq   |
  7  |  Lance    | Finance        |
  8  |  Lance    | Marketing      |
```

I configure my datareader as following below :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(IFormCollection form)
{
    List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();
    var fileName = "./Users.xlsx";
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            List<Skills> skilllist = new List<Skills>();  
            String username = string.Empty;  
            while (reader.Read() && !reader.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(0).ToString() == username)
                {
                    skilllist.Add(new Skills() { SkillName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()});
                }
                else
                {
                    UserModel user = new UserModel();
                    user.Name = username
                    user.SkillsList = skilllist
                    users.Add(user)
                    username = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    skilllist.Clear();
                    skilllist.Add(new Skills() { SkillName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The aim is using a local variable `skilllist` in which I would store each skills while the name is the same, then I will add it to the user SkillsList.
When the reader would find a new name, it would initiate a new list with the Clear() method, but I discovered it cleared also the list of the previously added users in "users"

-> Do you know how to proceed to solve this issue ? I've spent my day on it already

Please don't hesitate if you need more info, thank you in advance guys for your help :)

At the end I would like to have a table like this :

```
      1  |  Name     |     Skill      |
      2  |  John     | Accounting     |
      3  |           | Management     |
      4  |           | Production     |
      5  |  Liz      | Strategy       |
      6  |           | Fusion & Acq   |
      7  |  Lance    | Finance        |
      8  |           | Marketing      |
```

By using this code in my cshtml View :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td>Skills</td>
  </tr>
  @foreach (UserModel user in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@user.Name</td>
      @foreach (Skills skill in UserModel.SkillsList)
      {
        <td>@skill.SkillName</td>
      }
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Excel. The code isn't adding data to `UserMode.SkillsList`, it's using the same skills list for all users. Even if it didn't clear that list, all users would end up with the same skills, those of the last user.

`Clear()` doesn't create a new list, it clears the current one.

You could fix this by actually creating a new list :

```
UserModel user = new UserModel();
user.Name = username
user.SkillsList = skilllist
users.Add(user)
username = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();

skilllist=new List<Skills>();

skilllist.Add(new Skills() { SkillName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering :)

And yes it worked !

I thought I already tried it before but I used this line instead of yours that worked.
Mine threw exceptions because the list was already declared

```
List<Skills> skilllist = new List<Skills>();
```